# MERN stack application deployment to Heroku issues

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, mern

As the title says, when the application is supposed to be built and good, (at least during deployment, the log files etc always state that the build was successfull) when everything should be set to go, I open the site and encounter 2 console errors:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) favicon.ico:1

Tried looking up those errors and finding solutions but none of them seemed to work, Even though, the application works perfectly on local heroku (where you can test your app, in the heroku enviroment).

Not sure what I could do to fix my problem, as many forums suggest that you can't really do anything about it if it works fine on local heroku, it's must likely a server fault.

Thanks

edit: kinda fixed it myself after long days of struggling. Changed up file locations, moved server.js etc out from backend, into the main folder, and created a client folder, which now contains all the frontend stuff. Exact opposite what I used to have, since I used to have frontend out in the 'wild' and only had a backend folder for... well, backend files/folders/scripts.

Comment: It seems that the question is too generic to answer it. Try to provide more context. May be steps to reproduce problem could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... kind of, still not sure why the first version i tried to use didn't work, but at the end of the day, I'm fine with it